# Is it possible to call this stmt fetch sentence?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am new to PHP OOP and I have a question here. Is it possible to call fetch sentence like this?
`$this->stmt->fetch()`?

What I am trying to do is to define $stmt variable in my class and use it in a different methods, i.e:

```
class Display {
 private $connection;
private $stmt;

public function __construct ($connection) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
}

public function selectUsersValues() {
    $query = "SELECT name, surname, employment_date FROM employee";
    $this->stmt = $this->connection->dbh->prepare($query);
    $this->stmt->execute();
}
public function displayUsersValues() {

        while ($employee = $this->stmt->fetch()){
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$employee['name']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$employee['surname']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$employee['employment_date']."</td>";
    }
}
}
```

Basically in one method I want to just select the values and in the other method fetch all the results. Is it good thing to do or I have to do it just in `selectUserValues` method?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I had, but it says undefined `stmt` variable

Comment: also, your code has a missing echo "</tr>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am new to PHP OOP and I have a question here. Is it possible to call
>   fetch sentence like this? $this->stmt->fetch()?

Yes, it is possible.

> Is it good thing to do or I have to do it just in selectUserValues
>   method?

No, it's not a good thing because your client code could use the `displayUsersValues` method alone. That method has a temporal coupling to the `selectUsersValues` method that is not explicit in your code.
So you should `force` the users of your code (it may be even you, weeks later) to use both of them. You could do this refactoring:

```
class Display {
    private $connection;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct ($connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function selectAndDisplayUsersValues() {
        $query = "SELECT name, surname, employment_date FROM employee";
        $this->stmt = $this->connection->dbh->prepare($query);
        $this->stmt->execute();
        $this->displayUsersValues();
    }

    private function displayUsersValues() {

            while ($employee = $this->stmt->fetch()){
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>".$employee['name']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$employee['surname']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$employee['employment_date']."</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: your code has a missing `echo "</tr>";`

Comment: Man, thank you very much for your time. But could you explain just one more thing? What is that `temporal coupling`? You saved my life

Comment: `Temporal coupling` means that a piece of code depends on another piece of code to be run before it.

Comment: Also, naming is very important so you need to tell as much as you can from the signatures of your methods. The reader must find out what a method does just by looking at its signature. He/she must not understand *how* it is done but *what* it does.

Comment: I will try to improve my other method names, thanks for the advice!